# Data View not displaying

Tags: xpages

This is frustrating.  I have a custom control named "ccIndustryMaster" copied and renamed from the "ccProductMaster" custom control. There is a dataview in them but the view does not display on the web on the ccIndustryMaster but does display on the ccProductMaster.  My code for ccIndustryMaster dataview:

```
<xe:dataView
                id="dataView1"
                var="viewEntry"
                styleClass="product-master-tables"
                expandedDetail="true"
                multiColumnCount="#{javascript:return (deviceBean.isMobile()||deviceBean.isTablet()) ? '1' : '2' ;}">
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:panel
                        xp:key="detail"
                        id="detailPanel">
                        <xp:link
                            escape="true"
                            id="link1"
                            value="#{configBean.HostURL}#{sessionScope.LanguageURL}#{viewEntry.DocumentURL}">
                            <xp:table>
                                <xp:tr>
                                    <xp:td colspan="2">
                                        <xp:text
                                            escape="true"
                                            id="Subject1"
                                            value="#{viewEntry.Subject}"
                                            styleClass="title"
                                            disableTheme="true">
                                        </xp:text>
                                        <xp:text
                                            escape="true"
                                            id="SubjectTagline1"
                                            value="#{viewEntry.SubjectTagline}"
                                            styleClass="capacity">
                                        </xp:text>
                                    </xp:td>
                                </xp:tr>
                                <xp:tr>
                                    <xp:td styleClass="image">
                                        <xp:image
                                            id="image3"
                                            url="#{configBean.HostURL}#{configBean.HomeURL}/files/#{viewEntry.Image}/$FILE/#{viewEntry.Image}"
                                            alt="${document1.AltText}"
                                            title="${document1.TitleText}">
                                        </xp:image>
                                    </xp:td>
                                    <xp:td styleClass="description">
                                        <xp:text
                                            escape="true"
                                            value="#{viewEntry.DescriptionTrunc}"
                                            id="Description1">
                                        </xp:text>
                                    </xp:td>
                                </xp:tr>
                            </xp:table>
                        </xp:link>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xp:this.facets>
                <xe:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoView 
                        var="view1"
                        databaseName="${configBean.HomeDbPath}"
                        viewName="ProductFamilies">
                        <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript: var v =  new java.util.Vector();v.addElement(sessionScope.LanguageP);v.addElement(document1.getItemValueString("DocumentURL"));return v;}]]></xp:this.keys>
                    </xp:dominoView>
                </xe:this.data>
            </xe:dataView>
```

The Database and View names are filled in properly in the dataview Properties under the Data tab for ccIndustryMaster.  I went to the ccProductMaster (which the offending one was copied from) and changed the view name to "ProdInd" from "ProductFamilies", The view displays on that webpage.  On the offending page, when I change the view name to "Product Families" from "ProdInd" the view still does not display so there must be something wrong the the ccIndustryMaster custom control but I can't figure it out.
Any Ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you build the project after changes (= "Project/Build Automatically" is set or you clicked "Project/Build Project")? It feels like your changes don't take effect...

Comment: Yes I have.  I turned off build automatically and then build projects manually.  I even tried Clean and Build.

Comment: Is anything displayed when you inspect with the Developer Tools? The detailPanel? The link? The table??

Comment: Sorry for late delay in answer but I was on vacation.  Only tool I used was my own eyes examining code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the required summaryColumn which you can specify as a property or as a facet.

To get it to work quickly try changing the first few lines of the facets definition to the following:

```
 <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:panel
                    xp:key="summary"
                    id="detailPanel">
```